# Big query standard vs legacy syntax

Tags: regex, split, google-bigquery

the below functions works perfectly on sql legacy, but fails on sql standard with error:

"No matching signature for function REGEXP_EXTRACT for argument types: ARRAY, STRING. Supported signatures: REGEXP_EXTRACT(STRING, STRING); REGEXP_EXTRACT(BYTES, BYTES)"

```
 regexp_extract(split(something,','), r'^(.*?)\:')
```

I've tried to replace ' with ".. no success.
Any ideas?

Comment: `split` gives an array that is not supported. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a json column like the following {"X":2,"Y:1}
what i want to achieve is each key & value in different rows:
row 1[ x  |   2],  row 2 [Y  | 1]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `split` and `regexp_extract`, you could also drop into a UDF in JS that allows you to parse easily:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION parse(json STRING) RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
  LANGUAGE js AS """
        p = JSON.parse(json);
        arr = [];
        for (var key in p) {
          if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            arr.push(key + "|" + p[key]);
          }
        }
        return arr;""";
WITH foo AS (SELECT '''{"X":"2","Y":"1"}''' AS something)

SELECT parsed FROM foo, UNNEST(parse(something)) AS parsed
```

--

```
Row parsed  
1   X|2
2   Y|1
```

However, it's more code/SQL and probably a bit overkill for what you need. I just wanted to give you another option as I'm not a big fan of using regex!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ARRAY` function as a for-each loop over the elements that come back from `SPLIT`. For example,

```
SELECT
  ARRAY(
    SELECT regexp_extract(x, r'^(.*?)\:')
    FROM UNNEST(split(something,',')) AS x
  ) AS result
FROM table
```

Comment: here's the documentation on that topic: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#filtering-arrays